# Where is my Java compiler 1.8, in Eclipse?

Tags: java, compiling, eclipse, openjdk, jre

1. I installed openjdk8
2. In Eclipse (v3.8.1) -> window -> preferences -> Java -> installed JREs, I added the related standard VM.
3. In Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Java build path, I changed the JRE system library

   then, some of my project errors, related to Java 8 disappeared; but some others remained which, as I suppose, they are related to Compiler.
4. In Eclipse -> window -> preferences -> Java -> Compiler, I cannot see any version more than 1.7!

So, where is my Java compiler 1.8?!

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using  ?

Comment: it is Eclipse 3.8.1

Comment: try eclipse luna for Java 8

Comment: By this name, there is no suggested software in software center. But, mine is installed yesterday from software center and is completely up to date.

Comment: Ubuntu software center does not updated eclipse, you download eclipse linux version and install it.. i will put in answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older version of Eclipse does not support Java 8.

Eclipse Kepler SR2 & Eclipse Luna are the versions will support Java 8.

You can download Eclipse Luna from this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

And Eclipse Kepler SR2 also supports Java *, see this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

See this [link](http://difusal.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-install-eclipse-luna-44-on-ubuntu.html) to know how to install Eclipse Luna.